# Interaction effect in random forest

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, data-science

I'm interested in interaction effect between variables in random forest.
I found some information here [https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~breiman/RandomForests/cc_home.htm#workings](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/%7Ebreiman/RandomForests/cc_home.htm#workings).

> The operating definition of interaction used is that variables m and k interact if a split on one variable, say m, in a tree makes a split on k either systematically less possible or more possible. The implementation used is based on the gini values g(m) for each tree in the forest. These are ranked for each tree and for each two variables, the absolute difference of their ranks are averaged over all trees.
>
> This number is also computed under the hypothesis that the two variables are independent of each other and the latter subtracted from the former.
>
> A large resulting value is an indication of a repulsive interaction.

But I'm wondering if the large distance between splits on any two variables implies smaller absolute difference between their gini values?

And if this method can tell me anything about the type of this interection or I need use partial dependence for that?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This should be moved to Data science this is out of place here